# Python CSV writer - writing columns in new csv file up to maximum number of fields in csv files

Tags: python, csv, field

I have 200 CSV files in my folder.
What I am trying to do is read first row of each files and write in new csv.
And on top, I want to write [file,field1,field2,...fieldn]
n is maximum number of fields.

```
import csv
import glob 
list=[]
hel=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/dataset/*.csv')
with open('test.csv', 'w',newline='') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as infile:
            file=file[file.rfind('\\')+1:]
            file=file.strip('.csv')
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            headers = next(reader)
            hel.append((len(headers)))
            max(hel)
            lst = [file] + headers
            csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

It came out that maximum number of fields of 200 files are 255.
So on top of new csv file, I want to write `file, field1, field2 ... field 255.`
How can I do this?

---

```
import csv
import glob 
list=[]
hel=[]
files=glob.glob('C:/dataset/*.csv')
with open('test.csv', 'w',newline='') as testfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(testfile)
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as infile:
            file=file[file.rfind('\\')+1:]
            file=file.strip('.csv')
            reader = csv.reader(infile)
            headers = next(reader)
            hel.append((len(headers)))
            b=['field{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,max(hel)+1)]
            lst = [file] + headers
            csv_writer.writerow(lst)
```

Now `b` is list that looks like this ['field1','field2'...'field255']
I need to insert 'file' before 'field1' and write that row on the top of new csv file. Writing code after `csv_writer.writerow(lst)` gives me csv file with `'field1','field2'..` every other line. How can I fix this problem

Comment: to get the file name without the parent directory path, use `os.basename`, and use `os.splitext` to split up the file name into main part and extension part.  You should just write `file = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]`

Comment: Do you know the maximum fields before the program executes?  Or do you want to determine the number of fields in the program?

Comment: @frogcoder By doing `hel.append((len(headers)))`, program knows maximum number of fields among all files in folder. In this case, it was 255. Using that number, I want to write` ['file','field1','field2',...'field255'] `at the beginning of my csv file. When a file with 300 fields goes into my folder, there should be up to field 300 in new csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to read all your input files to determine the maximum number of fields is 255.  Then you need to construct a list of field names to write into the output file (just once, not in a loop):

```
['field{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 256)]
```

You can pass that list to the `csv` module to write it.

Comment: Thank you. Based on you answer, I edited my question. Where in my code should I use csv to write that list on the top of csv file. (1st row)

Comment: @김도훈: Just call `writerow()` once, not in the `for file in files:` loop.  That will make it write once, instead of many times.

Comment: Then `writerow()` in the `with open('test.csv', 'w',newline='') as testfile :` loop ?. Doesn't this write row at the end of csv file ?

Comment: @김도훈: Try it and see.

Comment: Yes. It does write at the bottom of csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Read the field count and first line from each file before writing the file.

```
import glob
from itertools import chain
import os
from os.path import splitext, basename

def first_line(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        return next(f)


def write_test_file(dest_file_path, source_path_name):
    source_paths = glob.glob(source_path_name)
    first_lines = list(map(first_line, source_paths))

    max_count = max(l.count(",") for l in first_lines)
    field_names = map("field{}".format, range(1, max_count + 2))
    header = ",".join(chain(["file"], field_names)) + os.linesep

    file_names = (splitext(basename(p))[0] for p in source_paths)
    content = chain([header], map(",".join, zip(file_names, first_lines)))

    with open(dest_file_path, 'w') as testfile:
        testfile.write("".join(content))


write_test_file('test.csv', 'C:/dataset/*.csv')
```

Comment: it's weird that now it does write `['file','field1','field2'..]` on top of csv file but from files, I think it's reading other rows because there are actual values inside.

Comment: @김도훈 sorry, I do not understand the problem.  Is there any problem with the result header?

Comment: Result header is fine. It successfully writes `['file','field1',..]` But below that is different from what I got from my code. My code reads first rows from csv files which are mostly field name but when I tried your code, there were actual values in it which means it reads other rows then write them on new csv file.

Comment: @김도훈 I misunderstood your question, I thought you needed first row of actual data from each file, it's an easy fix, I'll modify the code.

Comment: Yes. I just need to add one new row `[file, field1, .. field n]`. Everything else is fine. Thank you for the code. I will try it.